# When using a storyboard when does the OS set the rootViewController?

Tags: ios, lifecycle

I was surprised to observe that within `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` a call to `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController` returns `nil`.

I want to set some things up once on app launch where I need to reference the rvc, however this behavior means I'll have to do it elsewhere. 
If it can't be done in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` then the only other choice is `applicationDidBecomeActive`? But with the additional irritation (a small irritation, but still you'd think it shouldn't have to be necessary) of having to have a flag to ensure the set up steps only happens once and not every time `appliationDidBecomeActive` is called.

Is there somewhere else I can access the `rootViewController` on app launch to set additional steps up once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a `keyWindow` at that time in the application lifecycle, so the reason there's no `rootViewController` to get on the `keyWindow` is because `keyWindow` is `nil`. But the app delegate has a property for your `window`, so you can just get `self.window.rootViewController`.

However, if you always have the same root view controller, you could probably do at least some of what you want to do (maybe all of it) in your root view controller's `viewDidLoad` method. This generally should only ever be called once, because with iOS 6 and later your offscreen view controllers' views are never unloaded.

Comment: @Mungbeans I'm not sure why, because I can verify in apps of mine that it has a window (and root view controller) in that method. I would look to see if you made any changes that might have broken that property. Compare it to a fresh storyboard app created with a template to see what differs.

Comment: I found I don't have a problem with my project. It was due to this behavior of Xcode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785899/xcode-incorrectly-displaying-the-value-of-watch-variables

Comment: Ah. So you hadn't actually tried `self.window.rootViewController`, you had only tried to see if it was there using the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from window:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIViewController *rootViewController = self.window.rootViewController;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: There seems to be an issue with my project - as self.window.rootViewController is nil at that point

Comment: @Mungbeans `self.window` should not be nil in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, and definitely not later than that, so there must be something broken in your app that is resulting in that. I would suggest investigating why that's the case.