# Xcode incorrectly displaying the value of watch variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was scratching my head wondering why my rvc was set to nil when watching it while debugging through Xcode and thinking there must be something wrong with my project. So I created a project from scratch using the Xcode single view app template and then the only change I made was to add the following lines to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

[image]

Now look at what Xcode is displaying for the value of rvc in the watch window:

[image]

What's going on, why is it reporting rvc is nil?

Its not actually nil, but Xcode's watch window is reporting it as such. Is this a known issue with Xcode?

Comment: Is the build configuration set to Debug or Release? Check on Product > Scheme > Edit scheme...

Comment: In a single view project the window rootviewcontroller is not set yet.... u would have it set after the view didappear

Comment: I'm pretty sure  that you are receiving a warning saying that singleview projects are expected to have a rootviewcontroller before the didfinishlaunching :P

Comment: @Calleth. Please explain your confusing comments.

Comment: You have an AppDelegate property called window, but at this point this property has nothing set as rootviewcontroller.... when creating new singleview projects, you need to set the rootviecontroller before the DidFinishLounchingMethod is finished...

Comment: @Calleth. There's no need to set anything. The app template, of course, uses a storyboard and so the rootviewcontroller is being set automatically. Also it gets set before the applicationDidFinishLoading gets called. WHy do you repetedly keep saying its necessary to set it for single view projects, what is supposedly something different about single view projects? Mungbeans has already answered the question and shown the rootviewcontroller is being set and the issues is to do with XCode breakpoints.

Comment: "In a single view project the window rootviewcontroller is not set yet". Yes it is.

Comment: Omg, yes my bad, i was confused with the keywindow and the app window... sorry :/

Comment: This is normal.  The only way to be sure what the value of a variable is is to use the `p` and `po` commands in the console window.  The variable display is so unreliable as to be useless, most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem - its the positioning of the breakpoint, position it a line higher and rvc is not nil.

If you look at the watch window you can see rvc is light text when the other variables are bold text.

So my conclusion is at that point Xcode is reporting that rvc has gone out of scope and been deallocated, yet as the return statement has not yet executed at that point then rvc should not yet have gone out of scope.

Is it some Objective-C optimization thing going on resulting in this in Xcode or is it a defect with Xcode?

Either way its wasted a few hours of my time thinking I had a problem when there wasn't. In the future I need to make sure never to position breakpoints on a return statement again that contains local variables.